# Prepare statment with the fields as parameter strange result

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

i'm trying to parameterize the column in order to create a very dynamic query.
What i tried is:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->host.";dbname=myDB",$this->user,$this->pass);    
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$arr = array("g"=>"My Date","p"=>"Prono Score","a"=>"Age");
$param = "";
foreach($arr as $key=>$value) $param.=(':'.$key.',');
$param = substr($param, 0,count($param)-2);
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT $param FROM myTable LIMIT 1"); 
foreach($arr as $key=>$value) $query->bindValue($key,$value);
$query->execute();
$res = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $res;
```

Having that results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [My Date] => My Date
            [Prono Score] => Prono Score
            [Age] => Age
        )

)
```

What is my error? i don't know why it happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this line your binding placeholders called `g`, `p`, `a` to your select fields

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT $param FROM myTable LIMIT 1");
```

Then your assigning literal values to it with this line

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$value) $query->bindValue($key,$value);
```

Your really executing a query called

```
"Select 'My Date', 'Prono Score', 'Age' FROM myTable LIMIT 1"
```

Comment: if i choose bindParam the result is: Array ( [0] => Array ( [Age] => Age ) ), how can i change?

Comment: you can only bind literal values not column names, literal values can be bound to php variables, they are used in where clause or stored procedure (IN/OUT)

Comment: solution is create a stored procedure that returns the 3 values